# How correct use lock with Socket, NewtorkStream and SslStream?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, sslstream

I've got a server that uses a Socket with SslStream like this:

```
Socket senderSocket;

NetworkStream nStream = new NetworkStream(senderSocket, true);
SslStream ssStream = new SslStream(nStream);
```

I use the SslStream's synchronous *Write* and async *BeginRead* method. 
Before, I used the *BeginWrite* method instead of *Write*, and sometimes got an exception like this:

```
NotSupportedException: The BeginWrite method cannot be called when another write operation is pending
```

I guess this was thrown because my client has a Ping method.

Should I lock the Write method on my server? If so, should I lock the Socket or use Stream.Synchronized for SslStream?

Thank you